# Docker windows throwing error when trying to attach volume to C:\ inside container

Tags: windows, docker, containers, docker-volume

Docker command:

docker run --name container1 -it -v myvolume:C:\ file-utils-0.0.1.jar powershell

Response:

C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'myvolume:C:\': invalid mount config for type "bind": destination path cannot be `c:` or `c:\`: c:.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

It works fine when i mention folder name inside C: like C:\dummy

this command works fine

docker run --name container1 -it -v myvolume:C:\dummy file-utils-0.0.1.jar powershell

Comment: It would hide literally everything in the image.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to find out free space of host disk/directory mounted on the container, Then i faced this error.

Comment: every container by default get 20gb virtual space in windows, its showing free space of that virtual memory and i need to find free space of host directory attached to the container

Comment: Why do you need the container in that scenario? Just run the command on the host to check the space there.

Comment: I want to know the space from container perspective, For host anyway i can check locally.